# How does native sort method deal with sparse arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

When a sparse array is sorted `[5, 2, 4, , 1].sort() -> [1, 2, 4, 5, empty]`, the empty value is always last even with callback no matter the return statement.

I'm building my own sort method as a challenge and I solved this problem by using filter method since filter skips empty values. Then iterate over filtered array and set original array's index to filtered array's values. Then I shorten the original array's length since the remaining items will be duplicates, and I can finally feed it in my sorting algorithm. Once that's done, then I set it's length back to original which adds appropriate amount of empty items at the end. Here's a snippet of code, but here's [a link of the entire code](https://gist.github.com/aquaductape/791fd7e4eed252579a77ebc51f2ee1ab)

```
const collectUndefined = [];

// remove empty items and collect undefined
const removeSparse = this.filter(el => {
  if (el === undefined) {
    collectUndefined.push(el);
  }

  return el !== undefined;
});

const tempLength = this.length;

// reset values but will contain duplicates at the end
for (let i = 0; i < removeSparse.length; i++) {
  this[i] = removeSparse[i];
}

// shorten length which will remove extra duplicates
this.length = removeSparse.length;



// sort algorithm ...



// place undefineds back into the array at the end
this.push(...collectUndefined);

// restores original length and add empty elemnts at the end
this.length = tempLength;
return this
```

Is the native sort implemented in this similar fashion when dealing with sparse arrays, or no.

Comment: It has nothing to do specifically with the slots being empty. They're just non-numeric so all (in)equalities between them and numbers return `false`. It's likely an implementation detail in the algorithm that causes them to get moved to the end, and unlikely part of the specification. The built-in sort in JavaScript is, after all, unstable.

Comment: Notice: `[5, 2, 4, {}, 1].sort()` -> `[1, 2, 4, 5, {}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to implementation of `Array.sort` you have to also ask which engine? They are not all equal in terms of **how** they end up getting to the final `sorted` version of the array. For example `V8` has a pre-processing and post-processing step before it does `any` sorting:

> V8 has one pre-processing step before it actually sorts anything and
>   also one post-processing step. The basic idea is to collect all
>   non-undefined values into a temporary list, sort this temporary list
>   and then write the sorted values back into the actual array or object.
>   This frees V8 from caring about interacting with accessors or the
>   prototype chain during the sorting itself.

You can find pretty detailed explanation of the entire process `V8` goes through [here](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort#before-sort)

The actual source code for the V8 sort (using [Timsort](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort#timsort)) can be [found here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/78f2610345fdd14ca401d920c140f8f461b631d1/third_party/v8/builtins/array-sort.tq#L5) and is now in [Torque](https://v8.dev/docs/torque) language.

The js tests for V8 `Array.sort` can be [seen here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/test/mjsunit/array-sort.js)

Bottom line however is that nothing is actually removed from the original array since it should not be. Sort is not supposed to `mutate` the original array. That would be super `weird` if you call `myArray.sort()` and all of a sudden it has 5 elements less from its 8 total (for example). That is not something you would find in any `Array.sort` specs.

Also `Array.sort` pays close attention to the types it sorts and orders them specifically. Example:

```js
let arr = [4,2,5,,,,3,false,{},undefined,null,0,function(){},[]]

console.log(arr.sort())
```

Notice in the output above how `array` is first, followed by `numeric` values, `object literal`, `Boolean`, `function`, `null` and then `undefined` / `empty`. So if you want to really match the spec you would have to consider how different types are also sorted.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the links. I naively thought that the source code would be in js. What the V8 article shows on the process of sort, I can see how mine is very different. V8 sorts non-undefined array then assigns them to original array, while mine is the opposite. V8 is using timsort while I'm using merge sort(bottom up). Luckily my sort also outputs the same order of your array with different data types example.